# An easier way to calculate the cubes of all the $4$th roots of this complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to find all the possible values of $x$, where $x$ is
$$x=\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^\frac{3}{4}$$
here $i$ is the square root of $-1$.

Is there any other method other than finding the $4$ values of $\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^\frac{1}{4}$ and finding out the cube of each of them?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: use Euler's formula ($e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the complex exponential notation: as
$\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}3}$, $x$ will have a modulus of $1$, hence it can be written as $\mathrm e^{i\theta}$, and the equation becomes
$$x^4=\mathrm e^{4i\theta}=\bigl (\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}3}\bigr)^3=\mathrm e^{i\pi}
\iff4\theta\equiv \pi\pmod{2\pi}\iff \theta\equiv \frac\pi 4\pmod{\frac\pi 2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)^\frac{1}{4}=(\cos 60^{\circ}+i\sin 60^{\circ})^\frac{1}{4}$

By de Moivre's theorem:

$S=\cos 15^{\circ}+i\sin 15^{\circ} \lor \cos 105^{\circ}+i\sin 105^{\circ} \lor \cos 195^{\circ}+i\sin 195^{\circ} \lor \cos 285^{\circ}+i\sin 285^{\circ}$

Once again by de Moivre's theorem:

$S^3=\cos 45^{\circ}+i\sin 45^{\circ} \lor \cos 315^{\circ}+i\sin 315^{\circ} \lor \cos 225^{\circ}+i\sin 225^{\circ} \lor \cos 135^{\circ}+i\sin 135^{\circ}$

Comment: Are the minus signs needed?

Answer (score 0):

There are two equivalent ways to interpret the problem. Defining $ z :=  \frac 1 2 + i \frac{{\sqrt{3}}}{2} = e^{i \frac{\pi}{3}}$, for any complex number $x$ we can interperet the equation $x = z^{\frac 3 4}$ as $ x = (z^{\frac 1 4})^3$, meaning that $x$ is the cube of a fourth root of $z$, or we can interpret it as $x = (z^3)^{\frac 1 4}$, meaning that $x$ is a fourth root of $z^3$. I leave it to you to think about why the solution sets to these equations are the same.

You are asking if there is an easier way to solve the problem than using the former interpretation. Let's see what happens if we use the latter.

---

The possible values of $x$ (the fourth roots of $z^3$) are precisely the solutions for $x$ to the equation $$ x^4 = z^3 .$$ We have that \begin{align} z^3 &= \left(e^{i \frac{\pi}{3}}\right)^3 \\ 
                  &= e^{i \pi} \\
                  &= -1.
\end{align} Hence, we are looking for the solutions for $x$ to the equation

\begin{align} 
x^4 + 1 = 0.
\end{align} The problem has been reduced to finding the fourth roots of $-1$, which is not too different to finding the fourth roots of unity.

---

I am not sure if this method is "easier", as that is a subjective term. I personally prefer it since it reduces the problem to a routine exercise, and I am more used to finding roots of $-1$ than any other complex number (other than $1$).